# Use Go within a Qt C++ project

Tags: c++, qt, go

Is it possible to use a Go API in a Qt C++ project?

I would like to use the following Google API written in Go: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go

Comment: Please **edit your question** don't comment it

Comment: Why do you need to use Go? Cloud Speech has a [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a Go API in a Qt C++ project?

It could be possible, but it might not be easy and would be very brittle to run Go and Qt code in the same process, since Go and Qt have very different thread (goroutine) and memory models.

However, Go has (in its standard library) many powerful packages to ease the development of server programs, in particular of HTTP or JSONRPC servers.

Perhaps you might consider running two different processes using [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facilities. Details are operating system specific. I assume you run Linux. Your Qt application could then start the Go program using [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) and later communicate with it (behaving as a client to your Go specialized "server"-like program).

Then you could use [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) to remotely call your Go functions from your Qt application. You need some HTTP client library in Qt (it is there already under [Qt Network](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html), and you might also use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)) or some JSONRPC client library. Your Go program would be some *specialized* HTTP or JSONRPC server (and some Google Speech to Text client) and your Qt program would be its only client (and would start it). So your Go program would be some specialized [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). You could even use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s, [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets, or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s to increase the "privacy" of the communication channel.

If the Google Speech to Text API is huge (but it probably is not) you might use Go reflective or introspective abilities to generate some C++ glue code for Qt: [go/ast](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/), [go/build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/), [go/parser](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/), [go/importer](https://golang.org/pkg/go/importer/), etc

BTW, it seems that Google Speech to Text protocol is using JSON with HTTP (it seems to be some [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API)) and has a documented [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/), so you might directly code in C++ the relevant code doing that (of course you need to understand all the details of the protocol: relevant HTTP requests and JSON formats), without any Go code (or process). If you go that route, I recommend making your Qt (or C++) code for Google Speech to Text some separate [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) library (to be able to get feedback and help from outside).

Comment: As you can see in my edited question, I want to use an API on the client side. I can surely access this API through Qt Network but that is not what my question was about.

Comment: What is a proxy program? Do you have an example?

Comment: can you give me a link to this "go reflective or introspective abilities" stuff?

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! I'll go with the REST API that seems the more reasonable solution!